# Using Chained through time pattern of Optaplanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

Currently I'm using chained through time pattern to realize a continuous tasks with precedence limit,which means you have to finish the previous task then you can start the current task.The pattern is really convenient to help  me with the problem,and I don't have to write complicate rules to realize it.

Here is the question,I want to create two different chains.One is the machine tasks chain(tasks working on the machine continously),and the other one is  product tasks chain.The machine tasks chain has been done,but I using the same pattern to complete the product tasks chain,it failed.And I have no idea to modify it.Is there anyone who has the same question?

Comment: I've seen some cases which could benefit from 2 types of chains, but in the cases I've seen they went to the Moon before going to Mars. **Multi-stage planning** (see docs) is the Moon, fully uniformed planning is Mars. If today's business is first planning the vehicles and then a different team is planning the drivers, then automate it in phase 1 in the same way. Keep it simple and succesful first.

Comment: thanks a lot,I was wondering whether there was something designing problem with my domain model.And I am trying to change my model to realize two types of chain at the same time.Do you think that is possible? And my question is not about muti-stage planning.I just want to create two types of chain of the task,one is about machine,the other is about product.

Comment: And my target is to minimize the total task makespan and deliver the complete product to the customer before due time.But the problem is that it's kind of sequential production,which means that there are some tasks of a product(or kinds of products) that have to be scheduled on the right machine,and the first task has to be done,then the next task can start.So there exsist two typs of chain,tasks to be executed on one machine,and tasks of a product.I don't know the description is clear or not.Thanks again.